# Why does changing the if condition's position speed up my program?

Tags: javascript, time

I have written a sort algorithm with two loops (Insertion Sort) however what I've found is that when the condition of the second loop is

> j > 0 && value < inputArray[j - 1]

The loop runs faster than when the condition is

> value < inputArray[j - 1] && j > 0

This is written and ran by Node.JS on my computer.

```js
const makeEmptyArrayOfSize = function(targetArray, targetSize){
  console.time('ArrayMakingTime')
  for(let i = 0;i<targetSize;i++){
    targetArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * targetSize))
  }
  console.timeEnd('ArrayMakingTime')
  return targetArray
}
const slowerSort = (inputArray) => {
  console.time('slowerSort for ' + inputArray.length + ' records')
  for(let i = 0;i<inputArray.length;i++){
    let value = inputArray[i]
    let j = i
    for(;value < inputArray[j - 1] && j > 0;j--){
      inputArray[j] = inputArray[j - 1]
    }
    inputArray[j] = value
  }
  console.timeEnd('slowerSort for ' + inputArray.length + ' records')
  return inputArray
}
const fasterSort = (inputArray) => {
  console.time('fasterSort for ' + inputArray.length + ' records')
  for(let i = 0;i<inputArray.length;i++){
    let value = inputArray[i]
    let j = i
    for(;j > 0 && value < inputArray[j - 1];j--){
      inputArray[j] = inputArray[j - 1]
    }
    inputArray[j] = value
  }
  console.timeEnd('fasterSort for ' + inputArray.length + ' records')
  return inputArray
}
let dummyArray = makeEmptyArrayOfSize([], 10000)
let dummyArrayCopy = dummyArray.slice(0)
slowerSort(dummyArray)
fasterSort(dummyArrayCopy)
```

As you can see in the snippet above the only difference between fasterSort and slowerSort is the position of the **AND** (&&) conditions in the second **for** loop, however they evaluate at a huge difference in terms of time.

Comment: Possibly because `value < inputArray[j - 1]` returns false more often than `j > 0`, so testing the second condition is avoided more often when placed in that order. But really, it might be a quirk of compiler optimisation that may not be repeatable in other implementations (and therefore off topic as the answer is likely opinion based).

Comment: [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

I can see two things are playing important role:

1) Inside slower version just change a little code like

```
let m = inputArray[j - 1];
for (; value < m && j > 0; j--) {
  inputArray[j] = m
}
```

Now you will see some difference in the result.JavaScript array is different from what we see in a server-side language like c# where reading from the array is O(1), in JavaScript array is just an extension of an object.

2) The other as mentioned in comments is **Short-circuit evaluation**.